# how to keep image aspect ratio on API < 18

Tags: android, imageview

I have the next xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_areas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#9a05e7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/mapa_mask"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/mapa_default"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

There are two images "overlayed".

If I test the App on devices that have installed Android 4.3 or more ( >= API 18) the image aspect ratio remains perfect. But if I test the App on devices between API >= 14 API <= 17 the image is showed little "height narrow".

I used the next to set the correct sizes but it didn't work:

```
        // load the original BitMap (768 x 583 px)
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.mapa_default);
            // iv is an ImageView referenced in onCreate (mapa_default)
    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
    int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
    int newWidth = iv.getWidth();
    int newHeight = heightRealImg;

    // calculate the scale
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width,
            height, matrix, true);

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
    // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

    // set the Drawable on the ImageView
    iv.setImageDrawable(bmd);

    // center the Image
    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

This crash because the iv.getWidth returns 0. I think this is because the layout has not finished loading yet.

How can I keep the image aspect ratio??
Thanks

**My solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/my_frame"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_areas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#9a05e7"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/mapacyl_mask"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/mapacyl"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this case I manage the touch of "all" screen and I don't need get the width and height of the image or modify these values. And with fitXY the image expands and adapts to all screen sizes, ALTHOUGHT the ratio doesn't keep.

Thanks a lot @Doctoror Drive

Answer (score 3):

Why not use

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"?
```

Edit:
You don't need to do anything else in code.

You're misunderstanding the meaning of wrap_content and scale types.

wrap_content means that the View will be as small as the image and not larger than it's parent bounds.

fitXY means the image will be resized to fit the entire ImageView with not preserving aspect ratio.
canterCrop means

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

So maybe you want to try

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

[ImageView scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType)

Comment: centerCrop doesn't work, the top and the bottom of the image is "cutted", I don't know why because the height is set to wrap_content. Thanks for your time.